# Como agregar un evento a un elemento creado con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, funciones

Cree un boton dinamicamente con javascript y ahora quiero que cuando le de click se ejecute cierta funcion se que con jQuery seria de la siguiente manera:

```js
$(".elemento").on("load", function() {        
    // Codigo           
});
```

Mi pregunta es como hacer eso pero con JavaScript puro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De manera nativa JavaScript tiene la propiedad `onclick` para manejar el evento en cuestión. [Aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) puedes leer más sobre la propiedad.

Para un botón creado dinámicamente;

```js
var boton = document.createElement("button");
boton.innerHTML = "click";
document.body.appendChild(boton);

boton.onclick = function() {
  alert("Has hecho click");
};
```

Y para un elemento del DOM tomando su ID;

```js
var boton = document.getElementById("boton");

boton.onclick = function() {
  alert("Soy un botón");
}
```

```html
<button id="boton">Haz click</button>
```

En tu caso, si estas trabajando con el atributo `class` como en tu ejemplo, si tienes varios botones con la misma clase debes realizar un bucle `for` para que recorra todos los elementos con esa clase y aplique la propiedad;

```js
var botones = document.getElementsByClassName("boton");

for (var i=0;i<botones.length;i++) {
  botones[i].onclick = function() {
    alert(this.innerHTML);
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="boton">Boton 1</button>
<button class="boton">Boton 2</button>
<button class="boton">Boton 3</button>
<button class="boton">Boton 4</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

hay dos formas de lograr eso, una forma es usando un escuchador con `onClick`, ejemplo en el codigo del boton 1.

La otra forma seria agregando escuchador desde `javascript` con `addEventListener`

```js
function onClick() {
  console.log('AAA');
}

document.getElementById('boton').addEventListener('click', onClick);
```

```html
<input type="button" value="boton 1" onClick="onClick()">



<input type="button" value="boton 2" id="boton">
```

Answer (score 0):

corrección

```
<input type="button" value="click" onClick="clickButton()">
```

y en javascript:

```
function clickButton() { 
  //código
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function funcion(){console.log("Boton Presionado")}

$("#boton1").click(funcion);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="boton1">Boton 1</button>
    <button id="boton2" onclick="funcion()"> Boton 2 </button>
</body>

<script>
</script>
</html>
```